# How to track what causes memory leak in magento base project?

Tags: php, memory-leaks, zend-server

We have PHP based e-commerce platform running on Zend Server. It's a Magento-based platform and for the last few days, we are facing strange behavior in the PHP process.
But we are facing a memory-related issue i.e. Allowed memory size of `1073741824` bytes exhausted (tried to allocate `140055511388160` bytes)

```
[05-Aug-2019 11:37:07 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 140055511388160 bytes) in /opt/SP/WEB_DATA/zend/var/apps/http/URL/80/application/index.php on line 83
[05-Aug-2019 12:00:19 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 18446744069414588416 bytes) in /opt/SP/WEB_DATA/zend/var/apps/http/URL/80/application/index.php on line 83
[05-Aug-2019 12:35:15 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7234013555742498816 bytes) in /opt/SP/WEB_DATA/zend/var/apps/http/URL/80/application/index.php on line 83
[05-Aug-2019 12:39:00 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 140055511412736 bytes) in /opt/SP/WEB_DATA/zend/var/apps/http/URL/80/application/index.php on line 83
```

As per the logs, it is asking to assign more than `1400GB` which is practically impossible.